# SQL Server 2008 R2 database stuck in Restore

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, log-shipping

I have two SQL Server 2008 R2 servers one for PROD and the other for DR. I am trying to add log shipping for a database called School.

Steps so far

- Back up School database
- Restore with database using the UI or using the following SQL statement i.e.

  ```
  Restore database "School" 
  From disk ='t:\Data\School.bak' 
  with NoRecovery
  ```
- The result is database is stuck in Restoring
- If I restore the database with

  ```
  Restore database "School" 
  From disk ='t:\Data\School.bak' 
  With recovery
  ```

  The database restore completes but the log shipping fails.
- I have deleted the database and recreated it again using

  ```
  Restore database "School" 
  From disk ='t:\Data\School.bak' 
  With **NoRecovery**
  ```

  but it is still stuck in **Restoring state**.

Is there a way that I can restore the database without having the database been stuck in the restoring state.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like expected behavior to me.  Am I misreading something?

After you've restored the database and any differential or required transaction log backups with the `NORECOVERY` option, you need to tell SQL Server you're done restoring files.  The `NORECOVERY` option is specifically there to let you restore multiple files.

You should just need to run:

```
RESTORE DATABASE [School] WITH RECOVERY;
```

That will tell SQL Server you're done, and it will complete the restoration and it will no longer show up as restoring.

Answer (score 0):

> I have deleted the database and recreated it again using Restore database "School" from disk ='t:\Data\School.bak' with NoRecovery

you have to use below command as well,if you dont have any further logs

```
restore database databasename with recovery
```

**some more info:**

> Restore with database using the UI or using the following SQL statement i.e.

next time try to issue restore statement using tsql,so that you can know status

```
restore database databasename from disk="path"
 with stats=5
```

now if you want to know indepth details on where it is and what it is doing,you can use a trace flag  like below

```
dbcc traceon(3004,3605,-1)
GO
  restore database databasename from disk="path"
     with stats=5
```

this logs output to errorlog like below

> 2008-01-23 08:59:56.26 spid52      RestoreDatabase: Database dbPerf_MAIN
>   2008-01-23 08:59:56.26 spid52      Opening backup set
>   2008-01-23 08:59:56.31 spid52      Restore: Configuration section   loaded2008-01-23 08:59:56.31 spid52      Restore: Backup set is open
>   2008-01-23 08:59:56.31 spid52      Restore: Planning begins
>   2008-01-23 08:59:56.32 spid52      Halting FullText crawls on database dbPerf_MAIN
>   2008-01-23 08:59:56.32 spid52      Dismounting FullText catalogs
>   2008-01-23 08:59:56.32 spid52      X-locking database: dbPerf_MAIN
>   2008-01-23 08:59:56.32 spid52      Restore: Planning complete
>   2008-01-23 08:59:56.32 spid52      Restore: BeginRestore (offline) on dbPerf_MAIN
>   2008-01-23 08:59:56.40 spid52      Restore: PreparingContainers
>   2008-01-23 08:59:56.43 spid52      Restore: Containers are ready

For your current problem, you can look at event log as it will log current phase

> Is there a way that I can restore the database without having the database been stuck in the restoring state.

you will have to get the spid of the backup and see the wait type and troubleshoot accordingly

```
select * from sys.dm_Exec_requests where sessionid=backupspid
```

Comment: thank you for the reply. The restore completes with restore command but can i then rerun the restore with the with No recovery as i need to put log shipping on.

Comment: you can't run restore with recovery and then norecovery